# Model Validation / ASP.NET MVC 3 - Conditional Required Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-validation

I'm having trouble with my ASP.NET MVC 3 application. I have 2 propertiesin my model whereby I only want 1 of them required in my view based on whichever one is empty. So for example, if I enter a phone number then email is no longer required and vice versa, but if I leave both empty, then either 1 should be required, below is my model:

```
[Display(Name = "Contact Phone Number:")]
[MaxLength(150)]
public string ContactPhoneNumber { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Contact Email Address:")]
[MaxLength(100)]
public string ContactEmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Would I need to create a custom attribute to validate my model and if so, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can implement `IValidatableObject` on your class and provide a `Validate()` method that implements your custom logic.  Combine this with custom validation logic on the client if you prefer to ensure that one is supplied.  I find this easier than implementing an attribute.

```
public class ContactModel : IValidatableObject
{
   ...

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate( ValidationContext context )
   {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace( ContactPhoneNumber ) 
            && string.IsNullOrWhitespace( ContactEmailAddress ))
        {
             yield return new ValidationResult( "Contact Phone Number or Email Address must be supplied.", new [] { "ContactPhoneNumber", "ContactEmailAddress" } );
        }
   }
}
```

To get everything working at client side you'll need to add the following script to your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('form').validate(); 
    $('form').rules('add', { 
        "ContactPhoneNumber": { 
            depends: function(el) { return !$('#ContactEmailAddress').val(); } 
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: how about client side validation?

Comment: Probably hook into the jQuery validate plugin by adding a custom rule.    `$('form').validate(); $('form').rules('add', { "ContactPhoneNumber" :  { depends: function(el) { return !$('#ContactEmailAddress').val(); } } } );`  or similar

Comment: I've poked around a little bit but haven't found an easy way to create an attribute that hooks into the automated client-side validation framework.  If you're interested, you trace how the CompareAttribute is handled and see if you can extend the framework with something similar.

Comment: I took the liberty and added the client side code to your answer. +1

Answer (score 16):

Annotation-based conditional validation can be defined using [ExpressiveAnnotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations):

```
[RequiredIf("ContactPhoneNumber == null",
    ErrorMessage = "At least email or phone should be provided.")]
public string ContactEmailAddress { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("ContactEmailAddress == null",
    ErrorMessage = "At least email or phone should be provided.")]
public string ContactPhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MSDN blog entry about conditional validations: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have a solution, but I had a similar situation, so maybe my solution will prove helpful to someone else. I implemented a custom attribute with client-side validation. Here is my blog post: http://hobbscene.com/2011/10/22/conditional-validation/