# How to perform complex validation on a model object?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, entity-framework-4

My project is in ASP.NET MVC 3. In my domain I have a model object defined by Entity Framework. In order to validate properties I simply extend the generated EF object and add a metadata class which contains all my validation attributes.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ContactInformationMetaData))]
public partial class ContactInformation
{

}

public class ContactInformationMetaData
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [EmailValidator]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This works great most of the time but now I have a more complex scenario. I don't want the Phone and Email properties to be required but I want ONE of them to be required. In other words, I want to require that either email or phone or both be set, but not none.

How would I perform complex validation like this? If I create a custom validation attribute where would I put it and how would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another question **exactly** like that (even the Phone and Email example is the same):
[Model Validation / ASP.NET MVC 3 - Conditional Required Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242847/model-validation-asp-net-mvc-3-conditional-required-attribute)

Comment: Sorry. I obviously over looked a search result.

Answer (score 1):

Check out FluentValidation:

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc

you can easily create this type of custom validation, it's a pretty cool validation framework in general