# MVC 5 enable disable data annotation validation for some control

Tags: jquery, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-5

For one of my project requirement, i need to perform validation over some control.
(MVC 5 , Data annotation, JQuery)

Looking some different approach, i need data annotation validation handled through JQuery

```
  I have following control on my page with validation using data annotation on all these control:

  1) Username
  2) EmailId
  3) Contact No
  4) Password
  5) Confirm Password
```

Initially top 1-3 controls are blocked and and 4-5 control is set to display none
So, i need validation should not check for 4-5 when i press submit button.

Later it will show 4-5 control and 1-3 control is set to display none.
in that case i need validation should not check for 1-3.

NOTE:
There is only one View page, can't have multiple view pages

How can i enable and disable data annotation validation using JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for conditional validation.
various post for this:-

[Model Validation / ASP.NET MVC 3 - Conditional Required Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242847/model-validation-asp-net-mvc-3-conditional-required-attribute)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541244/Conditional-ASP-NET-MVC-Validation-using-Data-Anno

**Client side validation**

If you are using [jqueryvalidation.js](http://jqueryvalidation.org) by default it skips validation for hidden and display none element and if you want ignore validation for specific inputs you can do it by:-

```
$("#form1").validate({
  ignore: "input[type='text']:hidden",
   rules: {
     something: {
         number:true,
         min:1,
         required:true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: actually i m looking some different approach, i need dataannotation validation handled through JQuery

Comment: @sham so you need only client side condition validation. Am i right?

Comment: are you using jquery validation plugin?

Comment: ya, without that client side validation not possible.